# Form validation not working when appended by D3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, d3.js

I built a form with radio buttons using d3 as below:

```js
var rating_form = d3.select("body")
  .append('form')
  .attr('class', 'rating');

 // Appending up and down vote radio button
 var radio_groups = rating_form.append('div').attr('class', 'form-group');

 // Radio for up
 var radio_grp_chk = radio_groups
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'form-check form-check-inline upvote');
 radio_grp_chk
  .append('input')
  .attr('class', 'form-check-input')
  .attr('type', 'radio')
  .attr('name', 'voting-radio')
  .attr('value', 'thumbup')
  .attr("required", "");
 radio_grp_chk.append('span').text("upvote");


 // Radio for down
 var radio_grp_chk2 = radio_groups
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'form-check form-check-inline downvote');
 radio_grp_chk2
  .append('input')
  .attr('class', 'form-check-input')
  .attr('type', 'radio')
  .attr('name', 'voting-radio')
  .attr('value', 'thumbdown')
  .attr("required", "");
 radio_grp_chk2.append('span').text("downvote");

 // Appending text area
 rating_form
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'form-group')
  .append('textarea')
  .attr('class', 'form-control feedback-text')
  .attr('placeholder', 'Enter your text...');

 // Submit button
 rating_form
  .append('button')
  .attr('type', 'button')
  .attr('class', 'btn btn-primary rating-btn')
  .text('Submit!');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

For the `input` radio button, I add `.attr("required", "")` to make it compulsory to select before submitting. However, when I don't select the radio button and click submit, there is no error message that should appear.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your `.attr("required", "")`, the issue is just that your [button's type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) should be `"submit"` instead of `"button"`:

```
rating_form
    .append('button')
    .attr('type', 'submit')
    //etc...
```

Since `"submit"` is the default type you can also just remove the method `.attr('type', 'button')`.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var rating_form = d3.select("body")
  .append('form')
  .attr('class', 'rating');

 // Appending up and down vote radio button
 var radio_groups = rating_form.append('div').attr('class', 'form-group');

 // Radio for up
 var radio_grp_chk = radio_groups
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'form-check form-check-inline upvote');
 radio_grp_chk
  .append('input')
  .attr('class', 'form-check-input')
  .attr('type', 'radio')
  .attr('name', 'voting-radio')
  .attr('value', 'thumbup')
  .attr("required", "");
 radio_grp_chk.append('span').text("upvote");


 // Radio for down
 var radio_grp_chk2 = radio_groups
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'form-check form-check-inline downvote');
 radio_grp_chk2
  .append('input')
  .attr('class', 'form-check-input')
  .attr('type', 'radio')
  .attr('name', 'voting-radio')
  .attr('value', 'thumbdown')
  .attr("required", "");
 radio_grp_chk2.append('span').text("downvote");

 // Appending text area
 rating_form
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'form-group')
  .append('textarea')
  .attr('class', 'form-control feedback-text')
  .attr('placeholder', 'Enter your text...');

 // Submit button
 rating_form
  .append('button')
  .attr('type', 'submit')
  .attr('class', 'btn btn-primary rating-btn')
  .text('Submit!');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I don't want the page to refresh after clicking the button. The onclick listener will make some ajax call to send the form data. Is there a way to still keep `type=button` and validate the form?

Comment: Well, that's a different issue (even if related to your problem), so I suggest you posting a new question.

Comment: @hydradon By the way, when you post your new question, do not use the `d3` tag (since as you see the issue is not D3 related), use just `javascript`, `jquery` and `html`, that way you'll attract more attention.

Comment: sure, i will research some more first